# Is compass and straight edge geometry complete?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, decidability

Euclid's first three postulates are the basis of compass and straight edge constructions which are as complex as arithmetic.

The constructions themselves may be expressed as a formula with each of the six operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, complex conjugate, and square root corresponding to a simple compass and straight edge construction.

> **Q1** Do Gödel's incompleteness theorems apply in the feild of Compass-and-straight edge-constructions ?
>
> **Q2** Do we have any problems in compass and straight edge constructions which have **neither been constructed nor proved impossible**, and may just be un-decidable ?

The question asked nearly two months back   [here on maths.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454105/82412) got many opinions but no answers.>

The opinions ranged from addition of new postulates to Tarski's Elementary Geometry (in order to make it inconsistent) to finding a  (weak) subset of Peano Arithmetic which can be encoded as a statement in Euclidean Geometry.

**EDIT**

We talk of statements such as

> 

- $\mathcal construct$ regular $(2^{2^n}+1)$-gon :
  **undecided; maybe undecidable** (  taken from a comment by @AngelaRichardson, based on [Gauss–Wantzel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon#Detailed_results_by_Gauss.27_theory))
- $\mathcal construct$ regular n-gon : **decidable; True**
- $\mathcal construct$ trisection of angle $\theta$: **decidable;
  False**(Is this how you classify impossible constructions)

**Motivation was to introduce undecideability without a direct referance to arithmatic** not withstanding the fact that each of the above bullets would have an equivalent arithmetical statement with the same decideability status;

constructability here may take into account the decideability of the  equivalent  arithmetical statement or the Construction itself [based, maybe , on a decision routine for Tarski's Elementary geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/q/142297/34859)].

Besides geometry, dynamical systems is another field which can be used to state  decidability problems ; of course the essential language remains that of arithmetic but the context changes.     ( [Decidability in dynamical systems](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/42/99/65/PDF/dynsys.pdf) )

Comment: It is fundamental in Goedel's work that arithmetic involves abstract variables and a universal quantifier. Do you want your language of compass and straight edge geometry to have variables and a universal (or existential) quantifier? Does it have "or"? Does it have "and"? Does it have "not"? I guess you need some more details about the sort of sentences you allow in your language before you can start proving theorems about your language.

Comment: The question is not quite precise, but you seem to be basically asking either whether the quadratic closure of $\mathbb Q$ is decidable, or whether the theory of quadratically closed fields (of characteristic zero) is decidable. I don’t know the answer, but seeing as $\mathbb Q$ as well as every number field is known to be undecidable, I’d think there is room enough between the quadratic closure and the (decidable) algebraic closure for the former to be undecidable, though OTOH the undecidability results for $\mathbb Q$ and friends, which work by interpreting $\mathbb Z$ in the structure, ...

Comment: ... tend to rely on properties of quadratic forms, and I guess these won’t work for quadratically closed fields.

Comment: Hmm, or actually, since you have complex conjugation (or equivalently, you can specify the real part of the field), you are effectively working with Euclidean fields. The theory of Euclidean fields *is* undecidable: http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/Ziegler.pdf

Comment: Now that I think about it, I was probably answering a different question. The question really needs to be made more precise in order to make sense.

Comment: Euclidean plane geometry is complete and decidable.  What's unclear in your question is if you mean a theory strictly weaker, or not.  And if so, you probably have to state clearly what theory you have in mind to give a clear answer.

Comment: @arsmath Euclidean plane geometry is complete and decidable : is there a reference for this ?

Comment: The Wikipedia page states the result on the page for Tarski's axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms), it doesn't seem to cite a source.  The proof goes by showing that Tarski's axioms essentially axiomize real closed fields, and then prove that the first-order theory of real closed fields is decidable by quantifier elimination.

Comment: Note that in the Tarski result, one can decide any question of plane geometry, in the language where one can perform real number arithmetic and quantify over points (and hence over lines, circles, ellipsoids, parabolas, etc.). But one cannot quantify over "compass and straight-edge constructions" in that language, and this would in effect involve a quantification over the integers, which would cause undecidability. This kind of issue is why it is imperative to be precise about the language one for which one is seeking decidability or undecidability.

Comment: The fact that the first two examples start "Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$" suggests that the relevant decision problem concerns Arithmetic rather than Elementary Geometry. This resonates with the previous remark of Joel David Hamkins.

Comment: @AdamEpstein A "regular n sided polygon" is a part of elementary geometry; though I fully agree that in the first *Construction* problem,  arithmetical over tones can not really be blocked out

Comment: @AR I completely agree the motivation for these particular  arithmetic questions is geometric in nature,  It's  what makes it them so interesting as compared to, say, some other arithmetic question whose  formal statement is within a small Hamming distance :)

Comment: On a different note, but still  somehow topical, I am reminded of my post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105478/finite-dimensional-real-division-algebras. In turn, my unstated motivation for that was certain algebraic questions in  the dynamical of rational  maps in one complex variable. In both settings there is natural number quantification in some theory capable of support inductive arguments - for example, PA  - grafted  to a decidable theory - ACF(0). For some time now  I have been curious what, if any literature,  exists regarding such  grafting.

Comment: @AT Granting the nuance of the edit, assertions such as "There exists a construction" or "The following recipe yields a construction" are not statements in the language of Elementary Geometry, but in some informal language about computational algoritihms, whose formalization yields statements in the language of arithmetic.

Comment: Yes I would say the  ingredients for the construction recipe would be the axioms of geometry ( in question); however it would be possible to express the recepie in any other ( equal or stronger )axiom set; as per ones taste.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a precise formulation, which shows the problem to be open.

Let $L$ be the language of Tarski-style geometry, with the two relations $Collinear(p,q,r)$ and $Equidistant(p,q,r,s)$.

Let $E$ be the constructible numbers, and $R$ the real numbers.  Then $E$ and $R$ are structures for $(+,\times)$, and $E^2$ and $R^2$ are $L$-structures.  $Th(E^2,L)$ is the first-order theory of $E^2$ in the language $L$.

Then I believe: **$Th(E^2,L)$ is decidable iff $Th(E,+,\times)$ is decidable.**  Whether that decidability holds is an [open question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142395/is-the-field-of-constructible-numbers-known-to-be-decidable?rq=1); if so, there is a complete recursive axiomatization of that theory.

I can envision a decision procedure for simple sentences about $E^2$, which would rely heavily on the algorithm for deciding sentences about $R^2$.  We can enumerate constructions and algebraic symmetries, enough to either verify constructibility, or show an element of odd order in the Galois group that prevents constructibility.  Given a potential construction or symmetry, we can check if it has the right properties using the Tarski procedure.  I've never seen this all written down, but in principle someone could have done it all in the 50's.

For the particular sentences you mention, the sentences and decision procedure would look like this.

- For trisectability, we have the sentence "For any angle $PQR$, there are congruent angles $PQX$, $XQY$, $YQR$ inside it."  We decide that this is false in $E^2$ by finding the element of odd order in the appropriate Galois group.
- For constructiblity, for each $n$, we have the sentence that "there exist $P_1\ldots P_n$ forming a regular $n$-gon".  We decide this either by finding the construction, if $n$ is of the appropriate form, or by finding the element of the Galois group, as before.

This account of the question isolates whether constructibility adds any incompleteness or undecidability to geometry.  It avoids immediately dragging in the Godel phenomena of the integers.  Whether we can define the integers in $E$ or $E^2$ is the content of the open question.