# What is known of the reverse math of Riemann-Roch?

Tags: lo.logic, riemann-surfaces, reverse-math

I hope this is not too trivial, but I think this may be well known to someone (not me).

Comment: Just the classical form?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse math"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics

Comment: At least over an algebraically closed field, any given instance will be provable  in that complete theory. On the other hand, the  usual assertion which  quantifies over  all line bundles  is indirectly making some statement in the language of arithmetic, much as here:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105478/finite-dimensional-real-division-algebras

A priori, the same questions apply.